# How Do I Setup NHibernate.Burrow With Fluent?

Tags: .net, asp.net, orm, nhibernate-burrow

I'm very interested in using NHibernate.Burrow for my session handling and DAO in my ASP.NET app but I'm having trouble with the configuration. Burrow requires an XML NHibernate config for setting up its persistence but I don't have a config file since I'm using Fluent NHibernate to generate my config. So is there a way of letting Burrow know of my Fluent configuration? Hope this makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not configured Burrow with FNH, but I know it's possible to inject additional properties into the NHibernate configuration with Fluent NHibernate.

Line 117 of this Unit of Work file shows how properties can be combined with FNH config.

http://gist.github.com/108433

Line 150 shows where these properties are actually used in the FNH configuration.

Answer (score 2):

http://andyhitchman.wordpress.com/2009/02/24/fluent-nhibernate-with-burrow/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.reversealchemy.net/2009/08/27/configuring-nhibernate-burrow-using-fluent-nhibernate/